# How to pass props in my dynamic component

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing this completely dynamic rendering, I have a question, in the title and subtitle props, I want to pass a value that is in the map, I don't want to pass it hardcode, but I don't know how I could pass it.

```
   interface Props {
  questions:any[]
}

interface OptionsSurveys {
  [key: string]: JSX.Element;
}

const FindSurveyComponents: React.FC<Props> = props => {
  const { questions } = props
  const components: OptionsSurveys = {
    'star-rating': <StarRating 
      title={'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.?'}
      subtitle={'Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s'}
    />,
    'slider-grade': <SliderGrade
      title={'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.?'}
      subtitle={'Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s'}
    />,
    'default': <Textarea
      title={'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.?'}
    />
  }

  const mappingComponents = () => {
    return (
      questions.map((question:any) => {
        const SurveyComponent = components[question.style]
        return SurveyComponent
      })
    )
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {questions && mappingComponents()}
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

UPDATE:

I managed to change it like this and now I can send the props to each component, I only have a doubt in which type to place what it is, put any

```
  const components: any = {
    'star-rating': StarRating,
    'slider-grade': SliderGrade,
    'default': Textarea
  }

  const mappingComponents = () => {
    return (
      questions.map((question:any, index:number) => {
        const SurveyComponent = components[question.style]
        return <SurveyComponent key={index} />
      })
    )
  }
```

Comment: Just to understand, you can't use an object instead of an array for questions or an array of objects?

Comment: First time I do something like this, if you give me an example, I would appreciate it :)

Comment: Well, maybe using an array, like: ```[{style: 'star-rating', title: 'you title', subtitle: 'your subtitle'}]``` and just change your function mappingComponents to handle with the new data. It is just an explanation.

Comment: Check my update, can you think of something for the typing? Thanks